# Django Admin fields named "name" acting strangely

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have a model defined like so:

```
class Country(models.Model):
    """ A three taps country reference
    """

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True)

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'crawler'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Countries'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return " ".join([self.name, self.code])
```

In my admin.py:

```
admin.site.register(Country)
```

And registered directly with django admin. When I pull up a detail view for one country, the name field doesn't fill in the actual name, but is a number field with a +1 -1 toggle.

http://cl.ly/image/0r39093b3a3S

If I try to save changes without touching that field, it fails saying it is required. What is going on? Further, this is the code when I inspect the form element:

```
<input class="hide input-mini suit-sortable" 
    id="id_name" maxlength="200" name="name" 
    type="number" value="United States">
```

So I see that it is there, but being hidden for some reason, and written as type number.

This is actually occurring to every "name" field on each model in my application. If I change the field name to something other than "name" it works fine. What is going on?

Comment: Can you show your `admin.py`?

Comment: added more info about the question

Comment: Why do you have `type="number"`? Its clearly not a number field.

Comment: I don't understand your statement. The type="number" is generated by Django Admin. Of course it isn't a number field. I didn't define it as a number field. It somehow becomes one.

Answer (score 0):

By default all the fields are required for the form. To specify field is not required, set `required=False`.

That being said you can't register the model in the `models.py` itself. Create a file `admin.py` in the same directory where there is `models.py`.

```
from app_name.models import Country
from django.contrib import admin

admin.site.register(Country)
```